# Error in Laravel vue inertia creating search with pagination

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am a beginner in using Laravel 8 with vuejs and inertiajs. I am trying to make a pagination search table. I am following tutorials to achieve this but I have error.

Here is my binded input type from vue:

```
<input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control float-right" placeholder="Search" v-model="term" @keyup="search">
```

Here is my whole script from vue:

```
<script>
    import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout'
    import Paginator from "@/Components/Paginator";

    export default {
        data() {
          return {
            term: ''
          }
        },

        props: {
          members:Object,
          filters: Object
        },

        components: {
            AppLayout,
            Paginator,
            // JetPagination
        },

        methods: {
          search() {
            this.$inertia.replace(this.$route('member.index', {term: this.term}))
          }
        }


    }
</script>
```

Now in my laravel controller, here is what i've followed from tutorial:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {           
        return Inertia::render('Members/Member', [
            'members' => Member::with('user')->when($request->term, function($query, $term) {
                $query->where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%');
            })->paginate()
        ]);
    }
```

I have an issues/warning/error in my console:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler 
Uncaught TypeError: this.$route is not a function
```

Comment: did you import `vue-router` in your `app.js`?

Comment: I am using inertia link for my router. Is it not enough ?  Or how can I utilized the inertia route ?

Comment: I don't know how inertia works but when you call `this.$route` I think it calls the vue-router maybe something like `this.$inertia.route` work but try to put the syntax on your config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base on the [documentation](https://inertiajs.com/routing)

you should do like this:

```js
export default {

  data() {
     term: '',
     routes: {{ json_encode($routes) }}
  }

  ...

  methods: {
    search() {
      this.$inertia.replace(this.routes('member.index', {term: this.term}))
    }
  }
}
```

You should pass then `json_encode` to your data and access it.